# @apply not working in tailwindcss | Next.js in global css file

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base{
body {
    @apply bg-[#06202A] text-grey-300; 
}
}
```

@apply is not woking css global file in Nextjs with tailwindcss i also used mode to jit but still not working ,need help ...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIq5f.png)

Comment: [Please follow this link for solution with latest tailwind and nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67679410/nextjs-not-able-to-use-custom-colors-in-tailwind-css-in/70121053#70121053)

Comment: [Follow this link for latest answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67679410/nextjs-not-able-to-use-custom-colors-in-tailwind-css-in/70121053#70121053)

Answer (score 1):

`@apply` is a way to use own custom CSS made with Tailwind directive within the common CSS file. Therefore, bg-[#06202A] must be declared before using it.

> You neeed to pre defined in your TailwindCSS file before use it.
> so these could be solution.

##### Siolution 1

```
@layer base{
   body {
       --body-bg-color: '#06202A';
       @apply bg-var(--body-bg-color) text-grey-300; 
   }
}
```

##### Solution 2

```
body {
   --body-bg-color:'#06202A';
   --tw-text-opacity: 1;
   background-color: var(--body-bg-color);
   color: rgba(209, 213, 219, var(--tw-text-opacity));
}
```

Also, the following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) will be helpful to you.
good luck, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

In current version (v2.1.4) it is not possible to `@apply` classes generated by JIT.
From [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode):

> You can only @apply classes that are part of core, generated by plugins, or defined within a @layer rule. **You can’t @apply arbitrary CSS classes that aren’t defined within a @layer rule**.

You can add [new color in config](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#colors).
For example
`blue: '#06202A'` and than you can `@apply bg-blue`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, just try adding

```
@tailwind apply;
```

and it should work as expected.

Comment: Can you explain further?